# Why are my images not working on my website?

Tags: html

So, I'm using HTML, and I need to upload photos, but the photos come up blank, checking in inspect, it says "cross-site context" and to do with cookies, I'm using Imgur as the image hosting website.

I've tried uploading it separate times, I thought that would be the issue, but it wasn't.

The code is

```
<!doctype html>
<div id="links" style="text-align: center">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</div>
<a href="nizhnyve.html">Home</a>
<a href="history.html">History</a>
<div id="image">
  <img
    src="https://www.imgur.com/ovBN6Vc"
    width="233.75"
    height="152.75"
    align="center"
  />
</div>
<div id="Header">
  <h1>
    Dameki C̣engarit Rešuto Ramivaj | <em>Tǣmeki Tsongārit Āʃutō Amlivāj</em>
  </h1>
  <h1>Helai Ġamelok | <em>Kǟngmä́ng Tēhmä́ng</em></h1>
  <h2></h2>
  <h2><em>The Government of the Federal Empire of Nizhnyve</em></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: You should edit your question to provide formatted code. That comment is unreadable. I don't know Imgur but `https://www.imgur.com/ovBN6Vc` is not an image, it is a whole HTML page.

Comment: It was working fine on the home page for this, so I dont know whats going on

Comment: The image's URL is https://i.imgur.com/ovBN6Vc.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image link you're wanting to use is https://i.imgur.com/ovBN6Vc.png. Replace your current image src attribute with this link and you'll be able to see your image.

Comment: That seemed to work, thank you.

Comment: Having the wrong URI is always the solution to this daily asked question.